# Find all products assigned a particular shipping group

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

What would be the best method to show all products in a particular shipping group? I'm up to try either a MySQL query or possibly find a way to add as a column within the products listing of Magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had time to learn how to do this myself (or at least found code I could work with).

I simply took the code and instructions from here: http://www.webfixnow.com/magento-add-manufacturer-column-to-admin-product-grid/

And altered it slightly to add the column:

```
$shipping_group_items = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code');
    foreach ($shipping_group_items as $shipping_group_item) :
        if ($shipping_group_item->getAttributeCode() == 'shipping_group')
            $shipping_group_options[$shipping_group_item->getOptionId()] = $shipping_group_item->getValue();
    endforeach;

    $this->addColumn('shipping_group',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Shipping Group'),
            'width' => '100px',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'index' => 'shipping_group',
            'options' => $shipping_group_options
    ));
```